# Avoid maven clean install on Spring Boot each time a Java class is changed

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a web application and I´m using **Spring Boot** to run it. Every time I make a change in a `.java` I have to make a `mvn clean` and a `mvn install` for this code to be updated in my running application.

Is there some workaround for this issue? Something like instant re-run on file save, or any way to make this process faster, maybe re-publishing only the `.java` code?

**PD:** The `.xhtml` views updates on the fly. If you need more app specific details just ask and I´ll post them. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** I´ve also tried the `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths` porperty, but still not able to reload.
[Dev tools - restart-additional-paths](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-additional-paths)

Comment: Are you using the dev tools of Spring Boot ?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @khmarbaise I´ve tried devtools but still not reloading.

Comment: @Dherik I´m using eclipse:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
Build id: 20180308-1800
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32

Comment: @MarioC, what the expected behavior for you? Turn on the `Build Automatically` (or something like that) on Eclipse and every change on Java it will compile only the java file. So, after any change, you can just run the spring boot and the changes will be there. Is this helpful for you?

Comment: It is turned on, but even reloading or relaunching the spring boot app its not reloading the `.java` classes. The expected behaviour would be that when I save and then restart the boot app the java changes take effect in my JSF app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below dependencies to your pom.xml, and it autodeploys your changed code in the embedded tomcat.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I´ve tried adding this to my `pom.xml` but still not reloading. I still need to do `clean + install`. Maybe I have somehow to add the specific location for the classes to reload?
I´m reading this docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html
... but still got nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spring boot then add dependency for `devtools` as well as add this property in yml or the properties file:

```
# for not restarting the server every time
spring.devtools.restart.enabled:  false
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Spring boot dashboard vscode extension and now things are fine ,I don't need to restart server for any change,In the extension I can just simply click on run ,And it runs the springboot app